# Regex to search for a word in a string in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, regex, string, search

I need to search all of my codebase for "Url" and replace it with "URL". If I search for Url in Visual Studio I also get all my variables with "Url" in it.

Anyone have a Regex I can use to only find Url within a quoted string e.g. "Use this Url:"?

**Edit**

I was looking looking for a quick and dirty way to find designer text and hard coded strings that had Url in the string and change them to URL.

Comment: Isn't there a "Find Whole Word" option in VS?

Comment: I know this isn't helpful to your situation necessarily, but this is one of the many reasons that string resources aren't just for localization.

Comment: Match Case and Find Whole Word will also find: 
enum values ( Url,)
Propreties (private string Url;)
Property uses (myClass.Url)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What I really ended up needing was:

```
("[^"]*Url[^"]*")
```

And thanks to the tip from [tghw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240194/regex-to-search-for-a-word-in-a-string-in-visual-studio/1240248#1240248) who pointed out the :q shortcut in Visual Studio equates to:

```
(("[^"]*")|('[^']*'))
```

I realized I needed to use the first portion to find only the double quoated strings I was looking for.

Both this regex and a standard find with 'Match case' and 'Match whole word' yielded results with some strings I was hoping to not find but eliminated the code with 'Url' in it.

Comment: This misled me, so I'm going to put in what I think is the right version: `"[^"\n]*Url[^"\n]*"` - otherwise it will return results where the word 'Url' appears on any line that is in between two strings, and because the find result only shows the first line, it looks like you get a false positive.

Answer (score 9):

Visual Studio has a "quoted string" operator `:q`. If you search for `:qUrl` with 'Use: Regular expressions' and 'Match case' on, it should find all instances of "Url" only in strings.

**Update**: The above is incorrect. :q just searches for a quoted string, but you can't put anything into it. My testing was just showing cases that looked correct, but were just coincidentally correct. I think instead, you want something like:

```
^(:q*.*)*(("[^"]*Url[^"]*")|('[^']*Url[^']*'))(:q*.*)*$
```

Comment: Ooohhh +1 for the :q. I didn't know that.

Comment: Unless I'm doing something wrong, it doesn't even find my example "Use this Url:", and it takes quite a bit of time to run even on a single 200 line document on my quad core.

Answer (score 6):

If you just quickly want to search for a quoted string you can use the "Use Wildcards" Find Option in Visual Studio.

For example:

```
"*Url*"
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the following to search only "whole words" (i mean: appearing with an space before an after or immedately after or before the " ):

```
(("[^"]*[ ]|")Url([ ][^"]*"|"))
```

For example this matches "test Url" and "Url test" but don't "testUrl".

Answer (score 0):

"Use this (Url):", then you can replace $1 (or whatever syntax Visual Studio uses). You may need to escape the quotes, and I'm not sure if Visual Studio lets you parenthesize parts of the regex.