# Visual Studio .Net - Find and Replace inside strings only

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio and I want to Find/Replace spaces with underscores in one of my classes.

However I am coding in C# and when using the standard Find/Replace dialogue box like so:

[image: FindReplace]

It also Finds and Replaces all of my whitespace, which I don't want.

Is there a way to perform a Find/Replace only inside strings?

Thanks

Comment: See [regex-to-search-for-a-word-in-a-string-in-visual-studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240194/regex-to-search-for-a-word-in-a-string-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Visual Studio regular expression flavour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx) - click the `Use` checkbox and select `Regular expressions` in the drop down.

Something like the following should work (it will match a string containing only whitespace and place the whitespaces in a capturing group):

```
"(:b+)"
```